# date checking for method update()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My function store() works, but I dont' know how to adapt in my method update() ??

```
$conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_revision_start)
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();

$conflictTraining2 = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_revision_end)
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();
```

Here is an idea of my function update(), but it's doesn't good...

```
$conflictTraining = Training::where('id', '!=', $id)
        ->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_revision_start)
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->first();

        $conflictTraining2 = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_revision_end)
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();

if( (isset($conflictTraining2) && $conflictTraining2->id !== intval($id))
        || (isset($conflictTraining) && $conflictTraining->id !== intval($id)) ){
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
             ->with('error', 'date duplicate ');
        }
```

Comment: did you get an error or you would like to optimize the code?

Comment: @AhmedAtoui: I don't have an error message, but my validation for the update() doesn't  work ... ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did face similar issue trying to solve time intersection, and I used datetime instead of just time to store interval.

To solve that, two methods were created, one to check internal period conflict and another to check external period conflict.

First, I suggest you to change your fields `start_hour` and `end_hour` to `start_time` and `end_time`, respectively, both datetime type.

Here a model sample with these methods

```
class Training extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'start_time',
        'end_time'
    ];

    public function isValidOrFail()
    {
        $collection = $this->all();

        $collection->each(function ($current)  {
            if($current->start_time and  $current->end_time) {
                if($this->hasConflictWithInternalPeriod($current) or $this->hasConflictWithExternalPeriod($current)) {
                    throw new InvalidPeriodException("Here my exception message");
                }
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    protected function hasConflictWithInternalPeriod($training)
    {
        return $this->start_time->between($training->start_time, $training->end_time)
            or $this->end_time->between($training->start_time, $training->end_time);
    }

    protected function hasConflictWithExternalPeriod($training)
    {
        return $training->start_time->between($this->start_time, $this->end_time
            or $training->end_time->between($this->start_time, $this->end_time);
    }
}
```

This may sounds a lot different of what you are expecting, but I hope it helps you.

You call method `isValidOrFail()`, it will check current model against all other records, validating internal and external period conflict.

Comment: Thank you a lot Luis Brito. ^^